# luaL_loadbufferx returns syntaxerrors

Tags: lua, lua-api

I'm working on a personal project and I'm trying to get Lua to work on my embedded device.
I have my own simple file system that works with the the flash drive, and now I'm trying to use modules for the lua scripts that I run on the device.

I have edited linit.c, to make it also load the modules that are existing in the flash drive, and it works for a few modules, but for most of them it just gives me a syntax error when it parses the contents of the module. I have a lua interpreter running on my Windows machine and the code I'm writing is syntactically correct and works, and the Lua API that I use is of the same version 5.4 on the device.

These are the arguments I pass to
luaL_loadbufferx(L, luaCFunction, sizeOfModule, moduleName, "t")
where, `L` is the lua state, `luaCFunction` is the lua module wrapped in a C-style return statement, `sizeOfModule`, `moduleName` and `t` is selfexplanatory.

Right now luaL_loadbufferx is called in a loop for every module in my flash-drive, I have overwritten the openf function from the Lua API for these external modules.

This below is one of the examples of a module that gives me
"Syntax Error: PANIC, unprotected error in call to Lua API
[string "module"]:3: '(' expected near 'writeobj'"

File: module.lua
Contents:

```lua
function writeobj()
    print('Hello World')
end
```

File: run.lua
Contents:

```lua
require ('module')
writeobj()
```

Does anyone know why this happens or did I not provide sufficient information? Please let me know.

Comment: The code you posted is correct.  The mistake is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I thought the modules passed to the buffer had to be of the LuaToC form, i.e. "return { ...luamodule...}", but changing it to pass the module only to loadbuffer was sufficient enough because it covers the case of it not being in a C style return format.

Comment: Although it is still strange that it gives out syntax error for only a few different modules when passing the modules in a C-style return format.